# How can I create a 4-D plot with points with different sizes for the fourth dimension? Python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, graph, charts

I would like to create a 4-D plot with points with different sizes for the fourth dimension. The first three dimensions are years, regions, and types of land covers. The fourth dimension contains the area for each specific land cover for regions in different years. I want to create a 4-D plot with three axes using years, regions, and types of land covers. I want to show the fourth dimension with points with different sizes corresponding to their area for each specific land cover for different regions and years. Python or Matlab preferred. Thanks in advance!!

I found a few references for creating a 4-D plot with different colors for the fourth dimension, but I want to creat a plot with points with different sizes instead of different colors.

Comment: This plot sounds like it would be completely illegible... for the sake of whoever is the consumer please consider a simpler data visualisation like breaking out into two or three linked plots. There is a reason some of these sorts of things don't have "off the shelf" solutions

Comment: I refered to the post below to resolve my own question by creating a chart with more than 3-dimensions:
https://medium.com/@prasadostwal/multi-dimension-plots-in-python-from-2d-to-6d-9a2bf7b8cc74

Thanks!